# Identical standard error for multiple predictors in mixed effect model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm running a 2*2*2*2 mixed effects design in R using the `lme4` package, on a number of different sets of similar data--running exactly the same model, just with a different subset of the data (but the same number of data points for each model).

The models (11 of them in total) all converge (for some of them I need to play around with the random effects), but in each model some subset of the fixed effects are getting identical standard errors. The value of that standard error is different across models, so it doesn't seem like this is some sort of floor effect of the computation. The estimates and t values are not identical, so this doesn't seem to be a data problem either.

Can anyone help me understand why, and if this should worry me?

The models are all like this:

```
lmer(data=data, Beta ~ L1L2*mod*cohort*time +(1 + L1L2*time | subj))
```

And the output of the fixed effects for one model looks like this:

```
Fixed effects:
                                   Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                        0.1026290  0.0074006  13.868
L1L2L2                             0.0119444  0.0025011   4.776
modspeech                          0.0140023  0.0022744   6.156
cohortHL1                          0.0015489  0.0074006   0.209
timet3                            -0.0040981  0.0022744  -1.802
L1L2L2:modspeech                  -0.0008333  0.0022744  -0.366
L1L2L2:cohortHL1                  -0.0020240  0.0025011  -0.809
modspeech:cohortHL1                0.0033475  0.0022744   1.472
L1L2L2:timet3                     -0.0015414  0.0022744  -0.678
modspeech:timet3                  -0.0068677  0.0022744  -3.020
cohortHL1:timet3                   0.0026211  0.0022744   1.152
L1L2L2:modspeech:cohortHL1         0.0009365  0.0022744   0.412
L1L2L2:modspeech:timet3            0.0008324  0.0022744   0.366
L1L2L2:cohortHL1:timet3           -0.0032911  0.0022744  -1.447
modspeech:cohortHL1:timet3        -0.0035383  0.0022744  -1.556
L1L2L2:modspeech:cohortHL1:timet3 -0.0006360  0.0022744  -0.280
```

While the output for the same model on a different set of data looks like this:

```
Fixed effects:
                                   Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                        0.0403691  0.0072784   5.546
L1L2L2                             0.0040910  0.0030953   1.322
modspeech                          0.0180205  0.0030953   5.822
cohortHL1                         -0.0009381  0.0072784  -0.129
timet3                            -0.0053620  0.0034053  -1.575
L1L2L2:modspeech                   0.0043932  0.0030953   1.419
L1L2L2:cohortHL1                   0.0036549  0.0030953   1.181
modspeech:cohortHL1               -0.0001598  0.0030953  -0.052
L1L2L2:timet3                     -0.0042556  0.0030953  -1.375
modspeech:timet3                  -0.0017538  0.0030953  -0.567
cohortHL1:timet3                   0.0044847  0.0034053   1.317
L1L2L2:modspeech:cohortHL1        -0.0051106  0.0030953  -1.651
L1L2L2:modspeech:timet3           -0.0009305  0.0030953  -0.301
L1L2L2:cohortHL1:timet3           -0.0045315  0.0030953  -1.464
modspeech:cohortHL1:timet3        -0.0012564  0.0030953  -0.406
L1L2L2:modspeech:cohortHL1:timet3  0.0005806  0.0030953   0.188
```

Similarly for the other 9 models, they each have identical standard errors across most of the fixed effects.

Answer (score 2):

Do you receive any messages of singular fit? In linear mixed models the standard errors are obtained as the square root of the diagonal elements of $$\biggl ( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i V_i^{-1} X_i^\top  \biggr )^{-1},$$ where $X_i$ is the design matrix of the fixed effects, and $V_i = Z_i D Z_i^\top + \sigma^2\mbox{I}$ with $Z_i$ the design matrix of the random effects, and $D$ the covariance matrix of the random effects. Hence, if the corresponding columns of $X_i$ for these are the same, you receive the same standard errors.

You could also try fitting the model with `lm()` and see if you get the same standard errors and/or messages that the design matrix is not a full rank.

Comment: There aren't any singular fits, but I think this is caused by the fact that most of the factors do not have random effects (either because they are not relevant, not important, or not possible in the case of between subject measures). it is exactly those categorical measures that do not have random effects that are getting identical SEs.

But should the SE not also be dependent on how much of the variance in the predicted variable is being explained by each predictor variable?